# mvc - Bind specific properties of ViewModel based on CheckBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model like this:

```
 public class EmploymentVM
{
    public string EmploymentType { get; set; }
    public string Employer { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public double GrossMonthlyIncome { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public string AutonomousActivity { get; set; }
}
```

In the view I have:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Employer)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Employer, new { @class = "form-control required" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Position)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Position, new { @class = "form-control required" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.GrossMonthlyIncome)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.GrossMonthlyIncome, new { @class = "form-control required digits" })
                </div>
```

and so on for the different properties.

The controller is very basic:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmploymentInfo(EmploymentVM vm)
    {
        //the actual code to save employment
        return View();
    }
```

I want to save the model with the property `AutonomousActivity` only if the user clicked the checkbox `IsAutonomous`, or save the properties `Employer` and `Position` if the checkbox is not checked.

How can I achieve that, does the model binder do that for me?

Comment: You have IsAutonomous in ViewModel?

Comment: no. That is just the CheckBox

Comment: Add it in the viewmodel and use it for conditional binding of data. Or use jquery to enable disable the fields when checkbox is checked or unchecked. Disabled fields data won't get posted to action. IMHO ViewModel way is easier to implement.

Comment: jQuery worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great! If you used jquery way you shouldn't mark viewmodel way as answer. Just upvote it as you aren't using it in your code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class EmploymentVM
 {
public string EmploymentType { get; set; }
public string Employer { get; set; }
public string Position { get; set; }
public double GrossMonthlyIncome { get; set; }
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
public string AutonomousActivity { get; set; }
public bool IsAutonomous { get; set; } //add in viewmodel bind it with checkbox

}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult EmploymentInfo(Employments vm)
{
   if(vm.IsAutonomous) {
    // you can set the value null/empty to any property
      vm.Employer =null;

    //save it 
   }
   else {
        // if checkbox is not checked
       //save it 
    }

    return View();
}
```